# How to collapse solution explorer view of razor pages?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I was coding with razorpages when randomly about 2 days ago the razor pages now display boths the cshtml and cs right away. earlier I could expand the cshtml to get to the cs file and i think it was a more compact that way

i think its options somewhere in tools->options->environment () but there are so many

after a few different google searches I found nothing helpful.
here is a picture of the problem:
 [image: picture]

earlier I could expand the cshtml to show the .cs files now i just see all of them and its kind of overwhelming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

enable file nesting in solution explorer [image: file nesting in vs]

Comment: Thank you, it was driving me mad, couldn't figure out why it was suddenly not nested

Answer (score 0):

They're not being nested, is all. It's literally two separate files, Visual Studio just recognizes that it's a Core project, and then shows them nested, since it understands that they're related. If that's not happening, then that means Visual Studio doesn't recognize it as a Razor Page, which could be a problem with VS, the project, or something else entirely. It's essentially impossible to say what the issue might be, so you'll just need to try stuff. A few things I can think of to try:

- If you're not using VS 2019, upgrade. Ultimately, this is part of the ASP.NET Core tooling, and best version of that is always going to be in the latest release.
- Verify that you solution is building correctly. You might also consider deleting all `bin` and `obj` directories and rebuilding to ensure the build is truly up to date.
- Close Visual Studio completely and re-open it. You may consider restarting as well. (You've probably already tried this though).
- Try running Visual Studio in "safe-mode", which essentially just means disabling all the extensions you have installed. You can either manually disable all your extensions and then restart or close Visual Studio and start it via the command like with `devenv /safemode`. If this fixes the issue, then there's an extension causing issues. You'll probably need to just disable each one by one to see which on is causing the problem, and then either remove it or see if there's an update that corrects it.
- If all else fails, repair Visual Studio. Run the intaller, and click the "More" link under the installation you're working with. Then click "Repair".

Comment: Or click on the Enable File Nesting icon :)